# How to change input border-color, with jQuery, depending on its value?

Tags: jquery, input, colors

I have question about jQuery. I have code below which works fine; it changes `input` `border-color` depending on its value, which is typed and entered. But if in `input`'s value on page-load it does not change that `border-color`. How can I make the `border-color` change from the beginning, following page-load?

Thank you :)

```
<input type="text" class="col" value="">


// When the <input>'s value changes
$("input").change(function() {

// If the value is less than 7, add a red border
if ($(this).val() < 7) {
    $(this).css("border", "5px solid red");
}

// Else if the value is equal to 7, add a green border
else if ($(this).val() == 7) {
    $(this).css("border", "5px solid green");
}

// Else if the value is greater than 7, add an orange border
else if ($(this).val() > 7) {
    $(this).css("border", "5px solid orange");
}

// Else if the value is anything else, add a black border
else {
    $(this).css("border", "5px solid black");
}

});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just trigger the event:

```
$("input").change(function() {
    // ...
}).trigger("change");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/9B5SX/1/

Answer (score 9):

I'd suggest:

```
$('input').on('change', function(){
    var v = parseInt(this.value, 10);
    $(this).css('border', function(){
        if (v < 7) {
            return '5px solid #f00';
        }
        else if (v == 7) {
            return '5px solid #0f0';
        }
        else if (v > 7) {
            return '5px solid #f90';
        }
        else {
            return '5px solid #000';
        }
    });
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wYr4c/).

Though honestly, given that *every* situation seems to require a `border-width` of `5px` and `border-style` of `solid`, I'd set those parts in the CSS:

```
input {
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

And simply update the `border-color` in the jQuery:

```
$('input').on('change', function(){
    var v = parseInt(this.value, 10);
    $(this).css('border-color', function(){
        if (v < 7) {
            return '#f00';
        }
        else if (v == 7) {
            return '#0f0';
        }
        else if (v > 7) {
            return '#f90';
        }
        else {
            return '#000';
        }
    });
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wYr4c/1/).

And, finally, just because I sometimes can't help myself (and while this approach *can* be taken, it's not one I can honestly recommend...), with added conditional operators:

```
$('input').on('change', function(){
    var v = parseInt(this.value, 10);
    $(this).css('border-color', function(){
        var v = parseInt(this.value,10);
        return isNaN(v) ? '#000' : v < 7 ? '#f00' : v == 7 ? '#0f0' : '#f90';
    });
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wYr4c/2/).

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: It is if the value could conceivably be `NaN` after the `parseInt()`, *never* trust your users, after all (though I did hesitate to retain the `else` for the same reason).

Comment: No no, I am not about `NaN`, I mean leave `return '#000'` simply without `else` :)

Comment: Oh! I see what you mean, yes; in that case the `return` would only be executed/encountered if no other conditions were met...gosh, I should go get some sleep... :D

Comment: It's time for Eurovision now ;)

Comment: Well, sleep it is, then! ;)

Comment: VisioN & David thank you for replys... But i have another problem... Your codes both are working on fiddle... But when i copy it to my file, does not work... I included jquery-1.9.1.min.js and everything did perfect on code but it doesn't work anyway :((( what should i do???

Comment: What's different in your page? Is your jQuery wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function (){/* your code in here */});`

Comment: David Thomas O my god... Shame to me :D:D:D:D Yes i missed that part :D:D Now everything is perfect!!! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here. On my case, the input was a table column and it was displayed for every table row. With the next code I managed to change only one input color, not all when I changed the value for one.

```
         $('input[type=number]').each(function () {

             /* Change border color depending on the input value */
             var value = parseInt(this.value, 10);
             if (value != 0) {
                 $(this).css('border-color', function () {
                     return value ? 0 : '#bfbfbf', '#f32d83';

                 });

             }
             else {
                 $(this).css('border-color', '#bfbfbf');
             }

         });
```

Hope it helps