# Jquery textbox event for border color change

Tags: jquery

How can I raise the event whenever textbox border color change? I want to assign textboxA border color to textboxB.

Comment: A textbox doesn't change color, hence there is no such event ?

Comment: Show some code what you are trying to do.

Comment: it probably changes on the `focus` event

Comment: What do you mean by _"raise the event"_ ?

Comment: how does it change ? if it was with js then bind both textbox to the same code

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

You can create a function that checks the css color change:

```
$('.foo').css('border-color').on('change',function(){
    //change other div border color
});
```

**Below is the old, inapplicable answer**

That depends, if you are changing the border color with CSS, on hover for example, then you can create a function that triggers on hover

```
.foo:hover{border-color: red;}

$('.foo').hover(function(){
//change other div border color
});
```

you can also use mouseenter and mouseleave.

If the initial border color change is done with JS, then go ahead and bind the new function there.

Comment: the OP says **whenever**, this only cover the `hover` case

Comment: I updated my answer to perform a check on css 'border-color' property. Thanks for the note!

Answer (score 0):

I hope your text box's color changes based on the value of the check box. If that is correct you can refer the link:

[How to change input border-color, with jQuery, depending on its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627760/how-to-change-input-border-color-with-jquery-depending-on-its-value)